# Firebase HTTP hosting

Tags: http, firebase, httprequest, firebase-hosting

This might look like a strange requirement, but I'm working on an IoT system and the "thing"s cannot send "https" request, but I still wish to use Firebase.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to serve my Firebase website over HTTP? Any alternative solution?

Comment: Firebase Hosting is only accessible over HTTPS. Asking for alternative services is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but I'm quite sure Googling it will give *a lot* of results.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, sure. I was thinking about a simple interface (e.g. http requests to https request) to keep my current hosting

Comment: Currently I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @jenny, this is a very specific problem. I'm interested to know what you are working on

Answer (score 0):

just follow the code of robertcedwards on Github

I've been working on this too

the only problem is the simultaneous connection that I am facing right now

I hope it can help you connect your IoT device to firebase through web server (http)